# What is the Trinity API

Tags: c++, api

I've stumbled upon a job offer that I'm really interested in and one phrase seems to daze me a little.

> Must be proficient in C++ and *Trinity* API (will be tested)

I have some knowledge of C++ and application programming interfaces, but I have no idea what "Trinity" refers to.

I've tried searching the internet but didn't find a decent answer that would really tell me what it actually means, or what knowledge it involves.

Any info would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well I guess it's not for you! It's probably referring to [Trinity Desktop Environment](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/) and [its API](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/trinity/current/kdelibs/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site should explain all you need to know about Trinity and the API:

http://www.trinitydesktop.org/